# git write access from Windows to MacServer

Tags: windows, macos, git

I tried to use git for versioning my project. 
My working PC runs with

- Windows 8.1
- git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 and
- TortoiseGit 1.8.11.0

The server at which I want to store the repository is a Mac with OSX. I can write/copy/delete files to the server in explorer. I create a bare-repository at the server with TortoiseGit from the WindowsPC. I check out the repo to a local drive, do some changes and commit them.

When I try to push the changes to the bare-repository i get the following error:

> git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master
>
> Counting objects: 110, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
>   fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Broken pipe
>   remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/66/377e54e90bfe7d0ed8a91acd823006a34a362b: Permission denied
>   remote: fatal: failed to write object
>   error: failed to push some refs to ''
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (3265 ms @ 14.11.2014 13:18:51)

The message tells me I don't have access to the folder but I can read/write files in the explorer.

If I use the file-protocol for data-transfer this should work or am I wrong?

If so, how can I force TortoiseGit to use this protocol?

Update1:
If I use the "git push" in the Git Bash environment I get exactly the same behaviour.

Update2:
If I use "git push file:////mainsrv01/" it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

TotoiseGit normally uses git-http as transfer protocol. Switching to SSH as transfer protocol solved the problem.